# How to stub a required module in a class?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, chai, sinon

I have a class which uses a database that I don't want to actually call. After digging around I found Sinon which seemed to solve this problem for internal methods but I can't get it to work with required modules. I know the test doesn't do much right now, but I want to confirm I can do this before going further.

When I do the below the db isn't being stubbed out.

The code I'm trying to test looks like this:

```
const db = require('../../models');
const Op = db.Sequelize;

class UserSearch{

  async _resolveUserType(userType){
    let permission;
    if (typeof userType === 'number'){
      permission = await db.permission.findOne({ where: { id : userType } });
    }else{
      permission = await db.permission.findOne({ where: { type : userType } });
    }
    return permission;
  }
}
```

The test code:

```
const db = require('../../models');
const { UserSearch } = require('./userSearch');

describe('UserSearch Test Suite', function(){
it('should return an object', async function(){
        const fakeDb = {
          permission: {
            findOne: function () {
              return new Promise(resolve => {
                return resolve({id: 3, type: 'student'})
              });
            }
          }
        };
        const userSearch = new UserSearch();
        sinon.stub(db, 'permission').returns(fakeDb.permission);
        const permission = await userSearch._resolveUserType(3);
        expect(permission).to.be.an('object');
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. After inspecting the db.permission object mid run I found it doesn't have a findOne method. It's calling the findOne method of the inherited Model class. By stubbing out permissions I was removing the inheritance link.

I changed the stub to

`sinon.stub(db.permission, 'findOne').returns(fakeDb.permission.findOne);`

and all worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but interesting. What if rewrite the cache?

```
const { UserSearch } = require('./userSearch');

describe('UserSearch Test Suite', function(){
it('should return an object', async function(){
         require.cache[require.resolve('../../models')].exports = {
          permission: {
            findOne: function () {
              return new Promise(resolve => {
                return resolve({id: 3, type: 'student'})
              });
            }
          }
        };
        const userSearch = new UserSearch();
        const permission = await userSearch._resolveUserType(3);
        expect(permission).to.be.an('object');
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stub first and after that call the function to be tested:

```
sinon.stub(db, 'permission').returns(fakeDb.permission);
const userSearch = new UserSearch();
const permission = await userSearch._resolveUserType(3);
```

If you do it the other way, then it will call the non-stubbed original function.

Typically you set up the stubs in the beforeEach() and clean up at afterEach() in your test suite.

And yes, your impression is correct in that sinon is well-suited for stubbing out the external dependencies in your unit to be tested.